# React nested routes working only on links

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using `react-router-dom` and `create-react-app` and I have 2 step routing in `index.js` and `App.js` and it works fine except in cases when I refresh the page or enter the link manually, then it redirects to the `/` root route which I don't want. It practically only works when I am clicking links on the page. How to solve this?

**index.js**

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={App} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

**App.js**

```js
const App = ({ logInUserWithOauth, auth, loadMe }) => {

  //...

  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
      <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
      <Route path="/feature" component={Feature} />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I protected routes with HOC and forgot about that.